# USB keyboard sometimes works sometimes it doesn't

Tags: 14.04, usb, keyboard

I'm using xubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have an IBM Model M keyboard with USB-SDL-6-pin adapter. The keyboard works fine on a Macbook Pro and on my desktop when I'm running Win7. The keyboard works at the bios screen and the grub menu. However, once xubuntu boots the keyboard fails to work very often. dmesg gives me this.

    `[94239.798037] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
    [94239.896671] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=154a, idProduct=0002
    [94239.896675] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [94239.896678] usb 1-1.3: Product: Input Device
    [94239.896681] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: ID Innovations Inc.
    [94239.908080] input: ID Innovations Inc. Input Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input38
    [94239.908263] hid-generic 0003:154A:0002.0029: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard       [ID Innovations Inc. Input Device] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0
    [94249.918111] hid-generic 0003:154A:0002.002A: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
    [94249.918137] hid-generic 0003:154A:0002.002A: timeout initializing reports
    [94249.918513] hid-generic 0003:154A:0002.002A: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [ID Innovations Inc. Input Device] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input1
    [94357.731852] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 10
    [94357.960908] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
    [94358.059834] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=154a, idProduct=0002
    [94358.059840] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [94358.059844] usb 1-1.3: Product: Input Device
    [94358.059848] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: ID Innovations Inc.
    [94358.068368] input: ID Innovations Inc. Input Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input39
    [94358.068567] hid-generic 0003:154A:0002.002B: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [ID Innovations Inc. Input Device] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0
    [94358.080163] hid-generic 0003:154A:0002.002C: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [ID Innovations Inc. Input Device] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input1`

The keyboard doesn't work when I connect it and dmesg says "usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed"

How do I fix this?

Edit: Additional info from lsusb:

Bus 001 Device 007: ID 154a:0002 Celectronic GmbH 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x154a Celectronic GmbH
  idProduct          0x0002 
  bcdDevice            1.05
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              5 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      59
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              6 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      97
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10